# form is not working when i am using the formgroup and service inside ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used the formgroup code in ngOnInit() and service also i used in ngOnInit(). Due to the asynchronous form is not working. below full code stackblitz url is working when i am using dymmy json inside the constructor. [working-form-dymmyjson CODE URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-dymmyjson2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I got response from the service. I have used service inside the ngOnInit(). Due to asynchronous call form is not working below is my code url with service. [notworking-form-using service stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-service?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Below is the service code 
 this.dataService.getData().then(data => this.users=data); I have tried formgroup code inside the service but getting errors.
 I got response in console attached screenshot.

[image]

Below is my constructor code:

```js
constructor(private dataService: DataService,private fb: FormBuilder) {
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
users: this.fb.array([])
})
this.users =[{"name":"manu","displayOrder":1,"data":[{"category":"electrical","name":"ele"}]},{"name":"divya","displayOrder":1,"data":[{"category":"tech","name":"ea_tcv"}]}];
this.test =   [{"name":"manu","displayOrder":1,"data":[{"category":"electrical","name":"ele"}]},{"name":"divya","displayOrder":1,"data":[{"category":"tech","name":"ea_tcv"}]}];
}
```

Below is my ngOnInit() code having the service and form initialization.

```js
ngOnInit() {
console.log("ramu");
this.dataService.getData().then(data => console.log(data));
this.dataService.getData().then(data => this.users=data);
this.dataService.getData().then(data => this.test=data);

let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
'name': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].name),
'category': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].category)
}));

let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
formArr.push(this.fb.group({
name: this.users[0].name,
displayOrder: this.users[0].displayOrder,
data: dataArr
}));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a method (or populate your form) in your callback `then` to populate your form after the values are cerainly there:

```
this.dataService.getData().then(data => {this.users = data; this.patch()});
```

and the method:

```
patch() {
  let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
  dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].name),
    'category': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].category)
  }));

  let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
    formArr.push(this.fb.group({
    name: this.users[0].name,
    displayOrder: this.users[0].displayOrder,
    data: dataArr
  }));
}
```

Your forked **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-service-4qczbn?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: It's work like a charm, thanks for rectifying error.